# Form Inside Accordion Panel omits field on submit

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces

Hi am trying to submit a form inside an accordion panel tab as follows:

```
 <p:tab title="SMS Configuration" >

                     <h:form id="smsFRM">
                         <p:messages closable="true" id="smsMessage"/>
                         <p:commandButton id="smsConfig" style="color:green;" update="smsFRM"  process="@form"  actionListener="#{setupController.updateSMSConfiguration()}" value="Save Configuration"/>
                         <br/><br/>
                          <p:blockUI trigger="smsConfig" block="smsFRM">
                             <p:graphicImage value="images/ajax-loader.gif"/> 

                         </p:blockUI>



                                 <h:panelGrid cellpadding="10" cellspacing="7" columns="2">

                                     <h:outputLabel for="userName" value="User Name"/>
                                     <h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter Gateway UserName" value="#{setupController.dbSetup.gatewayUserName}" id="userName" />
                                     <h:outputLabel for="apiKey" value="Secret Key"/>
                                     <h:inputSecret  required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter secret key" size="55" value="#{setupController.dbSetup.gatewayApiKey}"  id="apiKey" />

                                 </h:panelGrid>


                                  <h:panelGrid cellpadding="10" cellspacing="7" columns="2">
                                     <h:outputLabel for="enableAuditSMS" value="Enable Night Audit SMS"/>
                                     <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="enableAuditSMS" value="#{setupController.dbSetup.enableSMS}" />
                                     <h:outputLabel for="enableCheckoutSMS" value="Enable Checkout SMS"/>
                                     <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="enableCheckoutSMS" value="#{setupController.dbSetup.enableCheckoutSMS}" />

                                 </h:panelGrid>


                                  <h:panelGrid cellpadding="10" cellspacing="7" columns="2">
                                     <h:outputLabel for="checkoutSMS" value="Checkout SMS"/>
                                     <h:inputTextarea  id="checkoutSMS" value="#{setupController.dbSetup.checkoutSMS}"  cols="40">

                                     </h:inputTextarea>
                                 </h:panelGrid>




                         <br/>




                     </h:form>
                 </p:tab>
```

Problem: Only the last field `<p:inputTextArea/>` value is submitted to the backing bean.

Here is my backing bean method that's invoked once i hit the command button;

```
public void updateSMSConfiguration(){
        System.out.println("Enable sms --> " + dbSetup.isEnableSMS() + "Enable Checkout SMS ->" + dbSetup.isEnableCheckoutSMS());
        System.out.println("Checkout sms --> " + dbSetup.getCheckoutSMS());
         ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
           rtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
           try{
               setupFacade.edit(dbSetup);
               ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "SMS configuration Updated.", ""));
            // roomsFacade.setHouseKeepingTime();
               rtx.update("adminGrowl");
           }
           catch(Exception ex){
                ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "SMS configuration failed", ""));
               ex.printStackTrace();;
           }
            rtx.update("adminGrowl");
    }
```

The accordion panel itself is not nested inside a form. All other tabs are ok. I am using primefaces version 4.0 and glassfish 3.1.2. How can i solve this ? Thank You.

Comment: please include your p:commandButton. Can you try putting process attribute in your commandButton with the list of ids of your inputtext fields. ex (process="enableCheckoutSMS userName..."

Comment: @Fritz I've included it in the first snippet(view)..also tried to put the process attribute and it doesn't work either..

Comment: can you try using "action" attribute instead of the "actionListener" in your p:commandButton?